# MySQL - query multiplying records returned - Cartesian product

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am using the following query which is returning a huge number of duplicate records.

```
SELECT * FROM specimen, topography_index, morphology, functions 
WHERE 
SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code 
AND 
if(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.functions_code = specimen.snop_code) 
AND 
specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
ORDER BY 
(specimen.room = 'f') DESC,specimen.snop_code
```

The number of records being returned is around 59,000.  However, specimen table only has 469 records.  The morphology and functions tables have around 2000 records each, and the topography_index table has 29 records, so I'm guessing that the results are being multiplied by the number of records in 'topography_index' and 'morphology' or 'functions' tables (29 x 2000), whichever one that doesn't have a join in the if clause.

How should the query be written so that this doesn't happen?

Note that GROUP BY is NOT an option as the query is so slow with all the records being returned.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bda8/1

Perhaps this could be handled by a sub select statement in the if clause??

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check DISTINCT keyword to unify results on one or more of your columns

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to implement this..see SQLfiddle above

Answer (score 0):

Its my assumption if this doesnt work for you please create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with 4-5 records so that it would be easy to trace the error

change this

```
SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code
```

to

```
specimen.topography_index = SUBSTRING(topography_index.topography_index_code, 2, 2)
```